# How to position a text block over image regardless of image width

Tags: html, css, image, text, overlay

I am not well-versed with CSS and can't figure out how to keep a text block overlay relative to the width of my image. When I change the image width from 100% to 50%, the text block stays where it's at instead of staying "inside" the image.

**This is the code I'm using:**

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://xofarragio.com/resources/graphics/placeholder_1920x1280_01.png" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="text-block">
      <h4>Testing</h4>
      <p>This is a test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: update the width of the container, not the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's because your `text-block` div is positioned `absolute` to the `container`  div, and so it is only when that element changes that the `text-block` div will respond. You can simply change this by changing the with of the `container` element, as that is the parent that controls the position of the text-block
This is the code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 50%; /* only line added. Change wight here instead of in img*/
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://xofarragio.com/resources/graphics/placeholder_1920x1280_01.png" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="text-block">
      <h4>Testing</h4>
      <p>This is a test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Edit:** 
Answering your commented question,

1. To center the image on the page, you can add a wrapper div on top of the container that will take up 100% of the width, and then it would center the `.container` div.
   Changes to html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    ...rest of the code
  </div>
</div>
```

Changes to CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

2. To move the text box anywhere at all, you can just change the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties of the `.text-block` selector. so moving to the top right will be like so:

```
.text-block {
  /* ... */
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  /* ... */
}
```

and bottom left will be so:

```
.text-block {
  /* ... */
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  /* ... */
}
```

do you get the idea?

This is what it looks like:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 50%;
  /* only line added. Change wight here instead of in img*/
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <img src="https://xofarragio.com/resources/graphics/placeholder_1920x1280_01.png" alt="Nature" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h4>Testing</h4>
        <p>This is a test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. What code do I need to add or change if I want to:
1) center the image on the page
2) move the text box to the top right

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. The answers to your new questions are added with an edit.